# How to do computations simultaneously in multiple notebooks?

Tags: notebooks, parallelization

I have a Mathematica script which takes a few hours to run. I want to be able to open another notebook while it's running and do some other computations. I have enough many cores on my computer for this to be possible so it shouldn't be an issue.

What do I need to configure so I can be running several notebook scripts in parallel?

Comment: The question is indeed a duplicate, but for some reason I like this answer a bit more.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to `Evaluation->Kernel configuration options` and add a local Kernel (name it "2nd Kernel" or something). Then, in your second notebook, select in `Evaluation->Notebooks kernel` the kernel you just added. Your license must support additional kernels.

Comment: Ahh great, thanks a lot! You're my saviour :)

Comment: @Haffi112 You can also upvote together with an accept if it fits your needs :)

Comment: The upvote requires 15 reputations and I only have 13 >_< I'll keep it in mind :)

Comment: If you're using a second kernel, it is not necessary to set the notebook's default context.  It's not harmful...the two items are simply not related to one another.

Comment: Absolutely right, I'll fix it

Comment: Thanks @Volkar. Your answer was great for me! I always used terminal when I wanted to do parallel calculations, but I prefered to do all of them in nb!